# My reputation on Stack Overflow is reduced without any downvote

Tags: support

My reputation on Stack Overflow is reduced without any down-vote or any negative reputation points shown at **https://stackoverflow.com/users/704008/pranav?tab=reputation**. Two days ago my reputation was 951, I gained 4 points, but the total now is 943. Last night it was 951, in the morning it was 947, increased to 949 by afternoon and is now 943.

---

---

**Update:** I have checked **Show deleted posts**.

There isn't any downvote or anything in profile, but posts in which I participated (answered, edited or flagged) are deleted.

Is there a reputation point sloss of -2 when any post you answered or participated is removed?

This has only happened for past day.

---

---

Is this a bug?

Comment: Since your updated the question: Is there still something unclear to you?

Comment: @juergend , Why is it designed that way??? Also does it mean if I delete any downvoted answer/Question my reputation goes up again?

Comment: Yes, rep you lost from a downvoted post will be reverted if you delete that post. Discussing why something was designed like this would probably go too deep but I think it makes perfectly sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the bottom of the reputation page is a checkbox: *show removed posts*.

If you check it you see the entries where you lost rep from posts that got deleted. I am pretty sure there is an entry that explains your lost rep.

Comment: Is there reputation loss -2 when any post you answered or participated is removed. This is happening since last day only

Comment: @Pranav you lose whatever reputation you had gotten from the post.

Comment: @Pranav - You had at least four questions that you edited be removed by the auto-deletion process. The reputation you received for those edits was then removed. This is explained in one of the questions linked above.